# Storing data values in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, d3.js

Consider this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygdKA/5/) example. In this example I would like to use the var data values to be stored in a JSON file and being each data value to be assigned to a character string,like

```
{ 'mango':[2,2],'cherry':[3,3],'jackfruit':[4,4], 'apple':[5,4]}
```

And these values to be accessed by giving the name of the fruit.

```
 var data = [

[2,2],
[3,3],
[4,4],
[5, 4]
];
```

How store it and parse with a json file

Comment: How do you know what label goes with what data set?

Comment: Each label is assigned for each datapoint in the dataset

Comment: But how are the labels stored? Are they in an array?

Comment: Yes Andy they are in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for create the JSON array you can do so:

```
var name = ['mango', 'cherry', 'jackfruit', 'apple'];
var data = [
    [2,2],
    [3,3],
    [4,4],
    [5,4]
];
var outJson = {};

for( var index in data ){
    outJson[name[index]] = data[index];
}
```

For saving in a file I haven't understand what do you mean

Comment: TheGr8_Nik - I meant creating a separate Json file in which var data value is mapped to var name

Comment: On the server or on the client side?

Comment: TheGr8_Nik - On the server side

Comment: You can't do it directly, beacuse javascript run on client side (in the browser). You have to send your `JSON array` to the server and then save it.

Comment: TheGr8_Nik - How to do it on client side ?

Comment: Probably the best method is to use an `ajax POST` request to send your JSON array to an `PHP` file that save to the file

Comment: TheGr8_Nik - Thank you, have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986740/assigning-a-character-string-label-for-variable-co-ordinate-data . I want to do this with a csv file or a json file